# Linux stdlibc++ linker error on different computers

Tags: linux, software-distribution, libc++

I wrote an application in C++ for linux (X11, GLX) and it is working alright on my development computer (32-bit linux on 64-bit capable hardware). However, when I ran it on a 64-bit linux downstairs, I received an error telling me the linker failed to link stdlibc++.so.6, but I thought 32-bit compiled application could run on 64-bit kernels and Oses as well? At least that is the case in Windows... Do I have to separately compile 32 and 64 bit with different libs?

And how do I properly distribute my application? It's a game, and currently you have to run a makefile to let it move its dependencies to the /usr/lib/ directory (a kind of amateur installer). Will this work on all mainstream linux distro's? And are there better, neater ways to release your application?

Comment: You probably just need to install the required library.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` or your local equivalent.

Comment: Is this a standard problem that most linux users will be able to handle, or do I have to include that in the installer makefile? That would safe some confusing I would say...

Comment: Is it wise to recompile my source on a 64 bit system with 64 bit dependencies and distribute 32 bit and 64 bit separately?